# How to Upload a File on APEX 5 using dialog and jquery

Tags: file-upload, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I currently imported a page that uses jquery dialog to upload a file. This page has a button that calls the open dialog and then a .load get executed so a 2nd page can be loaded into the dialog. This 2nd page has a file browser so it can perform an upload when the dialog button (UPLOAD option) gets executed then an application process inserts the file into a table.

My question is. I'm new with apex and specially apex 5 because i only worked with apex 3.

That is the way it was done in the past. I'm just putting some of the code so you can get an idea.

This is a sample on how the button is working.
* button calls the formopen function

```
function FormOpen() {
  $('#MForm').dialog('open');
  $('#MForm').load('f?p=&APP_ID...........');
}
```

Here's the code for my jquery dialog, im just going to collapse everything on a single line to you can read it better

The function opens the dialog and loads the 2nd page into the dialog.

```
$('#MForm').dialog({
  width: 'auto',
  minWidth: 400,
  maxWidth: 600,
  resizable: false,
  autoOpen: false,
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Close',
      click: function() {
        $('#MForm').dialog('close');
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Upload',
      click: function() {
        uploadFile();
      }
    }
  ],
  modal: true
});
```

The Upload if its clicked calls an application process that is adding the file into the www_flow_file and I know i need to change it to the apex_application_files table. But that is not the issue.

The issue is that when I do this on apex 5 the page gives me this error:

Error: cannot call methods on dialog prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'close'
* If I try the file upload i get an error on the application process.

IS THERE A WAY OF DOING THIS EASIER on APEX 5?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a ["data loading wizard"](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/18.2/htmdb/creating-applications-with-data-loading-capability.html#GUID-951F611B-BCCF-4256-BFAF-ABE96CA56CDB) (latest documentation link but steps are similar in Apex 5) in application design mode that would be best to use instead of trying to make the old code work; Apex 5 will do 90% of your work for you.  Create a page, type of "Data Load" and a wizard will walk you through 4 or 5 steps to create a modal pop-up wizard set of pages.

Use that and that will save you a lot of headaches trying to migrate the old code.

Comment: that is not what I asked for Thanks

Comment: Yeah, I'm not smart enough to give an answer to your question, other than there is a lot of magic in Apex 5 that you'll have to emulate to get things going; wish I  could be more help.